# Do I need to provide an IFormatProvider when converting a date to a string with a specific format?

Tags: date, formatting, fxcop, iformatprovider

If I'm using this:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

FXCop complains that I'm violating CA1305 and says that I should provider an IFormatProvider.  Do I need to?  I'm asking for the date in a specific format anyway (which is the format I'm expected to put it into the XML as).

Would providing a format provider make any difference?  Might it actually produce the wrong results in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a bit more research it seems that in my instance it doesn't make any difference, but in the general case months might be displayed in a specific locale.

More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to specify the format provider?

If it is just laziness then I can recommend defining two snippets. **ic** for CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and **cc** for CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.

Never assume anything about how conversion to string works with the default culture. Not everyone in the world uses the gregorian calendar. Some day you customer might hire a contractor with a computer with another calendar as default and then you are not generating correct XML. Explain then to your customer that you didn't want to follow the FxCop recommendation.

---

Best thing would be if .Net included a Xml Culture. Then you could just do

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("d", CultureInfo.Xml)
```

For some reason Microsoft choose to create a separate class instead [XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx). The class has been there since .Net 1.0.

```
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Today, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

will always create a correct Xml date.

Not sure if it is bug or intended behaviour but `XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Today, "d")` will not create a valid Xml date.